# Display Banners inline and responsive with a given HTML structure

Tags: html, css, inline, responsive

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="bannerWrapper">
  <div class="bannerCollection">
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bannerCollection">
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to display all banners in 1 line and responsive, so they should resize all the same way on small screens.

This CSS did the job:

```
.bannerWrapper {
    display: table;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.bannerCollection {
    display: contents;
}
.bannerCollection .bannerUnit {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
.bannerUnit img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NoGo/8pzsk0m2/

My problem: I *cannot* use `display: contents;`, because this seems to cause problems with a Javascript selector.

Any chance to achieve this without changing anything inside `div.bannerCollection` and without using `display: contents;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design can be accomplished using flexbox. No need for display: contents.

Simply add `display: flex` to `.bannerWrapper` and `.bannerCollection`. Remove `display: table-cell` from `.bannerCollection .bannerUnit`

I modified your fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8pzsk0m2/5/

It's important to note browser support for display: contents is still fairly low, and depending on which browsers you are targeting, it may be wise to avoid its use until it's more widely supported.
https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20contents

Comment: That works great! Thank you! But how can I now center the `.bannerWrapper` block?

Comment: Nevermind: `justify-content: center;` was the solution (had never worked with flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.bannerWrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.bannerCollection {
    display: flex;
}
.bannerCollection .bannerUnit {
    padding: 0 3px;
}
.bannerUnit img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerWrapper">
  <div class="bannerCollection">
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bannerCollection">
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerUnit">
      <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```